# Ternary concatenation macro

Tags: c, macros, ternary-operator

I'm new to C and am trying to define a macro that sets a prefix to a char* (I am still visualising this as a string and I think this may be the cause of the confusion.)

```
#define setTxPrefix(xml, tx) (xml ? ("XML_" ## tx) : ("PSYS_" ## tx))
```

When xml is true, I want the "XML_" prefix. Otherwise I want the "PSYS_" prefix. I have already tried

```
#define setTxPrefix(xml, tx) (xml ? ((char*)"XML_" ## tx) : ((char *)"PSYS_" ## tx))
```

I am calling the macro like so:

```
transaction = setTxPrefix(1, "TransactionString");
```

The error I get is "user-defined literal operator not found", but I don't really get what would be the user defined literal here.
Any explanation to this would be appreciated.

Comment: Is macro concatenation is even needed? Can't you just do string literal concatenation? `transaction = "XML_" "TransactionString";`

Comment: The macro seems like a nice way to do the ternary check dynamically.

Comment: Still, the macro could use string concatenation instead of pre-processor token concatenation. You get slightly more type safety that way.

Comment: Aha, now I get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `#tx` to concatenate to a existing string. In this case "XML_" or "PSYS_". So, the code of the macro would be:

```
#define setTxPrefix(xml, tx) (xml ? ("XML_" # tx) : ("PSYS_" # tx))
```

*and* the code to call the macro should not have quotes:

```
transaction = setTxPrefix(1, TransactionString);
```

If the string in the macro has spaces in it, then you can use an interesting quality of C. That is, that string concatenation in the source becomes a concatenated string in the program. So you could change the macros this way:

```
#define setTxPrefix(xml, tx) (xml ? ("XML_" tx) : ("PSYS_" tx))
```

*and* the code to call the macro will have quotes:

```
transaction = setTxPrefix(1, "TransactionString");
```

Comment: Good answer, but I'm not sure aout the "if the macro has spaces" part. The stringisation will also treat arguments with spaces in them, i.e. `STR(1 + 2)` will become `"1 + 2"`.

Comment: @MOehm, yes, it might, but I'm not sure repeated spaces... Anyway, if it is an arbitrary complex string, then it is safer to use quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Token pasting with `##` is used to create valid C tokens from subtokens. You can't use that here, because you operate on string literals.

C will treat two adjacent string literals as a single string, so this should do what you want:

```
#define setTxPrefix(xml, tx) (xml ? ("XML_" tx) : ("PSYS_" tx))
```

This works if the second argument is a string literal:

```
puts(setTxPrefix(0, "Transaction"));
puts(setTxPrefix(1, "Transaction"));
```